# Image not being displayed, height and width resized to 0*0, but the original image is there

Tags: javascript, html, image

I'm trying to implement a static HTML template to CAKEPHP and is stuck in a problem. The main problem is I can't figure out why the problem is appearing. Below is the image that'll tell more.

[image: Image Slider Not Displaying]

The image (slider) that is being displayed in the static HTML version is not being displayed on the CAKEPHP version, while I've made sure all the necessary CSS and JS files are included, but no solution yet. Haven't faced this problem before, so what might be causing this?

I tried to fix the width and height of the image in the code but the image is still not being displayed and shows as 0*0 pixels as in the image.

Comment: Are you generating this image from a script or reading it and outputting it? You may need to check you've got appropriate headers sent and finish your alt attribute or remove it.

Comment: Yes, are you doing any modifications to the image in the process?
remove the alt .. and maybe if there is a fiddle or something that we can look that, that would be helpful

Comment: Not really, I'm not generating or doing any modifications to the image, just echoing it via CakePHP "<?php echo $this->Html->image('image-source.jpg', array('alt' => 'This is a slider.')); ?>" which basically should output the image. And in fact, the image IS output as shown in the chrome-inspect-element, but the problem is the image is just resized to 0*0 for whatsoever reason. ;? @avk Thank you guys for looking into it.

Comment: can you just put a simple image tag rather than using the helper function and see what the output is ?

Comment: I did, it's basically the same problem even when trying with <img src="image-source.jpg">. ;( @avk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem may occur when you have included multiple versions of jquery library at once. Make sure you have loaded single jquery file only.

The included jquery-slider may have been confused between two jquery files of different versions.